# How do I programmatically install a NuGet Package from a Cordova plugin?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, nuget-package

I'd like to create a PhoneGap/Cordova plugin for Windows. The plugin should install the Rate My App Windows Phone component (https://github.com/Microsoft/rate-my-app).

One step to complete installation is integrate the component via NuGet Package Manager.

How do I install the package programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [NuGet.VisualStudio](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.VisualStudio) or [NuGet.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Core/) to achieve this.

**NuGet.VisualStudio:**
Its useful if you use Visual Studio Extensibility tools.

```
var componentModel = (IComponentModel)_nugetServices.GetService(typeof(SComponentModel));
var installer = componentModel.GetService<IVsPackageInstaller>();
installer.InstallPackage(PackagesLocation, wizardproject, PackageName, PackageVersion, IsIgnoreDependencies);
```

Get more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/visual-studio-extensibility/nuget-api-in-visual-studio) about NuGet.VisualStudio.

**NuGet.Core:**

```
IPackageRepository repo = PackageRepositoryFactory.Default.CreateRepository("feed link");
PackageManager packageManager = new PackageManager(repo, "target location");
packageManager.InstallPackage(packageID, SemanticVersion.Parse("5.0.0"));
```

Get more info [here](http://blog.nuget.org/20130520/Play-with-packages.html) about NuGet.Core.